# Examples of torsion trace and torsion reject

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, torsion-groups

I am trying to understand the following examples in more details. Why are the following hold?? Can we prove it in details?

1. Let the class $$Y = \{Z_n:n=2,3,\cdots\},$$ then for each abelion group, the trace $\mathrm{tr}(Y)$ over $M$ is the torsion subgroup $T(M)$ of $M$. Also, $T(M)$ is the unique largest torsion subgroup of $M$, and $T(T(M))=T(M)$.

   If $M$ is an abelion group, then $\mathrm{rej}(Q)$ over $M$ is the intersection of all $K$ subgroup of $M/K$ torsion free. So $\mathrm{rej}(Q)$ over $M$ is just the torsion subgroup $T(M)$ of $M$, the unique smallest subgroup with $M/T(M)$ torsion free. And $T(M/T(M))=0$.

Comment: Hi, welcome to math stackexchange! Math writing can be formatted with [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M$ be an abelian group. If $x\in M$ has finite order $n$, then there exists $f\colon\mathbb{Z}_n\to M$ such that $x$ belongs to the image of $f$.

Hence every torsion element of $M$ belongs to the trace of $\mathcal{Y}$. In particular, $T(M)\subseteq\operatorname{tr}(\mathcal{Y})$. The converse is easy.

Consider a homomorphism $f\colon M\to\mathbb{Q}$. If $x\in T(M)$, then $f(x)$ is torsion as well, so $f(x)=0$. Hence $T(M)\subseteq\ker f$ and consequently, $T(M)\subseteq\operatorname{rej}(\mathbb{Q})$.

Since $M/T(M)$ is torsion free (prove it), all you need to show now is that, if $N$ is a torsion free group and $x\in N$, $x\ne0$, then there exists $f\colon N\to\mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(x)\ne0$. This relies on the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is divisible, hence injective as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Comment: Thank you sir, but I still need more detials,Do you define f or it is a result of trosion? if it is a result, could you text it please??

Comment: @HawraaAbbas If $x$ has order $n$, then the map $\varphi\colon\mathbb{Z}\to M$, $\varphi(z)=zx$ is a homomorphism; what's its kernel?

Comment: n and all powers of n

Comment: Multiples, actually. Apply the homomorphism theorem.

Comment: oh,, it is clear now.. Thanx alot